# How to change the textarea's value with this scripted function?

Tags: javascript, textarea

I want to change textarea's value by clicking web button.

I write something to textarea then click the button so the function could change 
the text within textarea.

However, nothing happens when I tried this code.

```js
function Josa(txt, josa) {
  var txt = document.getElementById("QQQQQ");
  var code = txt.charCodeAt(txt.length - 1) - 44032;
  var cho = 19,
    jung = 21,
    jong = 28;
  var i1, i2, code1, code2;


  if (txt.length == 0) return '';


  if (code < 0 || code > 11171) return txt;

  if (code % 28 == 0) return txt + Josa.get(josa, false);
  else return txt + Josa.get(josa, true);
}
Josa.get = function(josa, jong) {


  if (josa == '을' || josa == '를') return (jong ? '을' : '를');
  if (josa == '이' || josa == '가') return (jong ? '이' : '가');
  if (josa == '은' || josa == '는') return (jong ? '은' : '는');
  if (josa == '와' || josa == '과') return (jong ? '와' : '과');


  return '**';
}
```

```html
<textarea id="QQQQQ" rows="10" cols="100"></textarea><br/>
<button onclick="Josa()">convert!</button>
```

Comment: Have you tried taking out the arguments from your Josa function like this `function Josa()`, since you are not passing any arguments at any point.

Comment: to get the text, you need to take the value: `txt = document.getElementById("QQQQQ").value;`

Comment: `var txt = document.getElementById("QQQQQ");` will return a HTML DOM element..you have to use `txt.value` to get the input and why not paramter not `Josa()`

Comment: sorry, but yet nothing happens. (Though I followed everything all of you mentioned). I have no idea?

Comment: 1.added -.value, 2.deleted-Josa(josa, txt)->Josa(). but got nothing.

Comment: `onclick="console.log(Josa())"` - you do not do anything with the retured value

Comment: And I think you mean `if (code % 28 == 0) return txt + Josa.get(code, false);
  else return txt + Josa.get(code, true);`

Answer (score 0):

1. `txt = document.getElementById("QQQQQ").value;` // you need the .value
2. You are not using the return value anywhere
   `document.getElementById("QQQQQ").value=txt + Josa.get`
3. `if (code % 28 == 0) return txt + Josa.get(josa, false);` - there is nothing in `josa`

```js
function Josa(txt, josa) {
  var txt = document.getElementById("QQQQQ").value;
  var code = txt.charCodeAt(txt.length - 1) - 44032;
  var cho = 19,
    jung = 21,
    jong = 28;
    
  var i1, i2, code1, code2;


  if (txt.length == 0) return '';
  console.log(code)

  if (code < 0 || code > 11171) return txt;

  document.getElementById("QQQQQ").value=txt + Josa.get(String.fromCharCode(code), code % 28 !== 0);
}
Josa.get = function(josa, jong) {
  if (josa == '을' || josa == '를') return (jong ? '을' : '를');
  if (josa == '이' || josa == '가') return (jong ? '이' : '가');
  if (josa == '은' || josa == '는') return (jong ? '은' : '는');
  if (josa == '와' || josa == '과') return (jong ? '와' : '과');
  return '**';
}
```

```html
<textarea id="QQQQQ" rows="10" cols="100"></textarea><br/>
<button onclick="Josa()">convert!</button>
```

Comment: Sorry,but when I run this, yet failed. '영등포은' ->.'영등포가' should be the result what I expect. But, when I run this..'영등포은'->'영등포은**'.

Comment: only just '**' letters were added though this was not supposed to be happened.

Comment: I have no idea what the script is supposed to produce. I cannot read the characters. At least my script runs. Now the logic needs fixing